# Is it possible to easily add Angular 2 to ASP.NET MVC web core app project with Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-mvc

I would like to add Angular 2 to my new ASP.NET MVC web core project in Visual Studio 2017.
I can't find anything on NuGet related to this.

Is there some simple solution, perhaps a project template?

Answer (score 1):

There is template project for `asp.net core` with `angular universal` using `webpack` and server side rendering also can be set for VS2017 as well.

http://myview.rahulnivi.net/asp-net-core-angular-2-starter-kit-visual-studio-2017-project/

Template:
http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/10/04/angular2-template-for-visual-studio/